# Custom print factors/contrasts for lm

Tags: r, lm

I am looking for a way to edit how `lm` and `summary.lm` processing factor variables before printing.
For example I want to have coefficient like `Month: 6` not `Month6` - so adding additional space and `:` between variable name and the factor level. I do NOT want to split factor variable to separate columns - like `model.matrix`.

The best will be to might do it before lm is assessed as well after that and before `summary.lm`.

Example:

```r
> aa = airquality
> aa$Month = as.factor(aa$Month)
> # possible action
> ll = lm(Ozone~Month, aa)
> # possible action
> ss = summary(ll)
> ss

Call:
lm(formula = Ozone ~ Month, data = aa)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-52.115 -16.823  -7.282  13.125 108.038 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   23.615      5.759   4.101 7.87e-05 ***
Month6         5.829     11.356   0.513    0.609    
Month7        35.500      8.144   4.359 2.93e-05 ***
Month8        36.346      8.144   4.463 1.95e-05 ***
Month9         7.833      7.931   0.988    0.325    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 29.36 on 111 degrees of freedom
  (37 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.2352,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.2077 
F-statistic: 8.536 on 4 and 111 DF,  p-value: 4.827e-06
```

Comment: This is more like a hack, but perhaps you can try `aa$Month = interaction("", as.factor(aa$Month), sep = ":"); summary(lm(Ozone~Month, aa))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can over-write the `names` attribute of the `coefficients` member of the `ll` object:

```r
names(ll$coefficients) <- gsub("^(.*)(\\d)$", "\\1: \\2", names(ll$coefficients))
```

This means you get:

```r
ll

#> Call:
#> lm(formula = Ozone ~ Month, data = aa)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)     Month: 6     Month: 7     Month: 8     Month: 9  
#>      23.615        5.829       35.500       36.346        7.833
```

and

```r
summary(ll)
 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = Ozone ~ Month, data = aa)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -52.115 -16.823  -7.282  13.125 108.038 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)   23.615      5.759   4.101 7.87e-05 ***
#> Month: 6       5.829     11.356   0.513    0.609    
#> Month: 7      35.500      8.144   4.359 2.93e-05 ***
#> Month: 8      36.346      8.144   4.463 1.95e-05 ***
#> Month: 9       7.833      7.931   0.988    0.325    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 29.36 on 111 degrees of freedom
#>   (37 observations deleted due to missingness)
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.2352, Adjusted R-squared:  0.2077 
#> F-statistic: 8.536 on 4 and 111 DF,  p-value: 4.827e-06
```

For a more general solution, we can `gsub` out the names we find in `contrasts` with the names we find in `coefficients` (with modifications as suggested by the OP):

```r
iris2 <- iris 
iris2$Species2 <- sample(unique(iris$Species), nrow(iris2), TRUE)
ll <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, iris2)

for(i in names(ll$contrasts)) {   
  alts <- paste0(levels(iris2[[i]]), collapse = "|")   
  names(ll$coefficients) <- gsub(glue::glue("^({i})((?:{alts}))$"), 
                              paste0("\\1", ": ", "\\2"), names(ll$coefficients)) 
  }

summary(ll)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Species + Species2, 
#>     data = iris2)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
#> -1.27817 -0.25460 -0.06713  0.21136  1.44653 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>                      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)           2.37909    0.37679   6.314 3.17e-09 ***
#> Sepal.Width           0.75297    0.11084   6.793 2.68e-10 ***
#> Species: versicolor   1.42257    0.11514  12.355  < 2e-16 ***
#> Species: virginica    1.93784    0.10043  19.296  < 2e-16 ***
#> Species2: versicolor  0.11452    0.08981   1.275    0.204    
#> Species2: virginica  -0.02119    0.09440  -0.224    0.823    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.4368 on 144 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.7311, Adjusted R-squared:  0.7217 
#> F-statistic:  78.3 on 5 and 144 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks nice try, this was only an example. What to do when the factor levels are characters not numbers. check this out `library(ggplot2)
ll = lm(price~color, diamonds)
names(ll$coefficients) <- gsub("^(.*)(\\d)$", "\\1: \\2", names(ll$coefficients))
ll`. Of course I do not want to change them manually one by one for each factor variable.

Comment: @polkas that's an odd example because it is an ordered factor. The coefficients in the model don't match the factor levels as printed with `diamonds$color`. But see my update for a more general solution.

Comment: Yes, I think about characters for levels although diamonds ordered factors break sth. I want to point the numbers/characters difference for factors.

Comment: This loop across names(ll$contrasts) is a clue of this problem.

Comment: I have to revert approve because of this method is not secure - regex. `iris2 <- iris
iris2$Species2 <- sample(unique(iris$Species), nrow(iris2), T)
ll <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species + Species2, iris2)

for(i in names(ll$contrasts)) {
  names(ll$coefficients) <- gsub(i, paste0(i, ": "), names(ll$coefficients))
}

summary(ll)`. Variables with the same part name will be broken.

Comment: `iris2 <- iris
iris2$Species2 <- sample(unique(iris$Species), nrow(iris2), T)
ll <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Species + Species2, iris2)

ll$terms

for(i in names(ll$contrasts)) {
  alts <- paste0(levels(iris2[[i]]), collapse = "|")
  names(ll$coefficients) <- gsub(glue::glue("^({i})((?:{alts}))$"), paste0("\\1", ": ", "\\2"), names(ll$coefficients))
}

ll` 
It will solve this issue. I will approve your answer if you update it. Thanks

Comment: @polkas yes, that seems to work better. Updated.

Comment: last thing, changing of iris2 to iris (as you not defined such). Thanks once more